# How to pass multiple get parameters in my lambda function?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, path, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have multiple GET parameters so how should i pass in lambda function and how would my serverless.yml look like.Currently below is the configuration

**serverless.yml**

```
myFunc:
    handler: com.mcm.in.MyHandler
    events:  
     - http:
         path: user
         method: get
         cors: true 

Request:/mylist?page=1&size=10&filter=userId=abc&sort=-userId&version=1554304254262
```

Also how should i call in sls invoke local?

I have tried without the params,It's not working in serverless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a request template that will map your request contents using the parameters, as noted in [the documentation.](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#custom-request-templates) Your function will look something like this (if you want to take in the `page` parameter for example:

```
myFunc:
    handler: com.mcm.in.MyHandler
    events:
     - http:
         path: user
         method: get
         cors: true
         integration: lambda
         request:
             template:
                 application/json: '{ "page" : "$input.params(''page'')" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created the request template this way for passing multiple parameters in URL

```
template:
application/json: '{ "userid":"$input.params(''userid'')","activityid":"$input.params(''activityid'')"}'
```

Here is the full code

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
  likes:
    handler: handler.likes
    events:
      - http:
          path: /likes
          method: get
          integration: lambda
          reqValidatorName: xMyRequestValidator
          request:
            passThrough: NEVER
            parameters:
              querystrings:
                userid: true
                activityid:true
            template:
              application/json: '{ "userid":"$input.params(''userid'')","activityid":"$input.params(''activityid'')"}'
          response:
            headers:
              Content-Type: "'application/json'"
```